# Are netplan configuration evaluated dynamically?

Tags: 22.04, netplan

When applying a netplan configuration, is the configuration evaluated dynamically? For example will match keywords generate a static interface at apply time or will it be evaluated continously so that if I were to hotplug a NIC it could match it?